Why don't countries copy Estonia's remote voting system, given its nearly flawless track record over 20 years?
Estonia has used internet voting ("I-voting") since 2005, with over 50% of voters casting their ballots online in the most recent election. It remains the only democracy in the world where the majority of voters are eligible to vote online. Additionally, Russia plans to implement it nationwide by 2026, although critics argue the primary motivation is electoral fraud rather than an effort to increase voter participation.
Given Estonia's nearly flawless track record over two decades, why are other countries still hesitant to adopt a similar system and simplify voting for their citizens?
Prior research
The most comprehensive criticism of e-voting was published by Springall et al. in 2014. It outlined several issues with the system and ended with the following recommendation:

After studying other e-voting systems around the world, the team was
particularly alarmed by the Estonian I-voting system. It has serious
design weaknesses that are exacerbated by weak operational management.
It has been built on assumptions which are outdated and do not reflect
the contemporary reality of state-level attacks and sophisticated
cybercrime. These problems stem from fundamental architectural
problems that cannot be resolved with quick fixes or interim steps.
While we believe e-government has many promising uses, the Estonian
I-voting system carries grave risks — elections could be stolen,
disrupted, or cast into disrepute. In light of these problems, our
urgent recommendation is that to maintain the integrity of the
Estonian electoral process, use of the Estonian I-voting system should
be immediately discontinued.

However, from what I understand, many of the issues identified were addressed by 2021, and large portions of the online voting system were published as open-source for the sake of transparency. It is difficult for me to gauge the remaining risks, but Estonia continues using the system, and it seems to be functioning well for them so far.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Frame shift:  is there a widespread demand for new electoral tally systems, outside of the US?
Far as I know, most Western countries don't have big issues with voter fraud concerns.  They have plenty of other points of dissatisfaction, pushing the electorate to the edges, both on the right and on the left.
Look at the drama these last few years in the Netherlands, France, Germany,  UK, etc...  There is a large amount of discontent in Canada as well.
But are people saying:  "Wait, we need a new electronic system!  We are at risk of widespread fraud!"?
If it was proposed, do you think people would instantly trust whatever system gets chosen, because you and other experts say so?  Even if it was more secure?  Especially nowadays, when computers are widely observed to be hacked, including in government settings?
Then there are the implementation challenges.  Look at the UK, for example.  This is a country that has a recurring history of governmental IT project overruns, when it's not outright failure.
Ditto Canada, which screwed up both a Federal employees payroll system ($1B+) and the long gun registry ($2B which did include much non IT stuff).
Why would people prioritize that over say, reducing health care wait times?
Presumably, a parallel system would still have to be maintained to allow physical voting for those who prefer it that way, so savings would be illusory, as you'd still have to pay for capacity and widespread geographical availability on a duplicate system.
The one country that seems like it really wants to talk about the subject, the US, has, as far as I understand constitutional arrangements that prohibit the Feds telling the states how to run federal elections.  And, as far as is known, there is no real fraud happening, just a lot of hot air being thrown around, so even their need for a radical overhaul is debatable in actual practice.
So, where's the beef in the need for this to happen?  Estonia just started from a very, very, different place - no elections due to Communism - and is a very small country.

And, as far as is known, there is no real fraud happening, just a lot of hot air being thrown around => there's never been a full-scale audit of votes as per my knowledge that would definitively answer this question for a state as a whole. It's possible that there's enough fraud to tip the election in very close races. Though I guess the same could be said about Estonia too...

@JonathanReez In various cases in the US vote counting was challenged but in every case that was actually checked no actual vote tampering was found. Technically it is possible that there is fraud anyway. Technically it is also possible that all major government officials are just puppets of our secret reptilian overlords. This has been claimed by various people, no evidence was ever found but is possible that it is true anyway.

The argument about fraud would probably be that offline voting may allow fraud or even just mistakes on the small scale only, here and there, while electronic voting could allow it on a wider scale. Maybe Estonia was just lucky so far.

Frame challenge to your frame challenge. Other answers have highlighted that there is support in other countries for electronic voting, for example IVF Comes From The Tip mentions a survey in France showing 60% of people are in favour of it, although their main reason for this is convenience rather than concerns about fraud.

@quarague please see this follow up question

@quarague re the reptilians, I think "no evidence has ever been believed by enough people to matter" would be more precise ;) I'm sure some people found plenty of "evidence" :P

@James_pic If it came for free and was guaranteed to be secure, I'd probably poll for it as well, just for convenience.  The problem is when you move from polls to costing, execution and adversarial assessment of its robustness to interference.

@ItalianPhilosopher A quibble on your final sentence; the Soviet Union had elections, and my understanding is that at least at certain times, they made a big deal about people going to the polls. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1990_Estonian_Supreme_Soviet_election had around a million voters; unfortunately, while you can go back to the 1985 and 1980 elections, which were one party, it doesn't show you how many people voted, whether Estonia had a Soviet history of popular voting, even if one-party.

You could have added more examples of IT disasters in the case of Canada (ArriveCan, Ontario's kiosks). The current paper ballot system is inexpensive (volunteer and temp staff, uses public schools etc. as voting stations), simple, can be audited and yields reliable results in hours in most cases. The only reason to go to more high tech systems would be to allow more votes such as referenda and that does not seem like a high priority of governments.

as far as I understand constitutional arrangements that prohibit the Feds telling the states how to run federal elections => correction, it’s other way around. Feds can’t control state elections (with limited exceptions, se forced bussing) and states can’t control federal elections rules (also with exceptions).

Depending on political traditions and social cohesion, it may be desirable that results can be tracked by non-technicians so that "ordinary people" don't have to trust the admins and programmers appointed by the election authorities.
In germany, a random person could stand close to the ballot box all day and observe the ballots going in, and then watch the ballot box being opened and the ballots getting counted (provided the number of self-appointed watchers does not disrupt the orderly conduct). If that person perceives a difference, he or she cannot directly interfere, but she or he can publicly raise a stink later on. I've never seen people watch, but that people could watch without prior notification helps to maintain faith in the results, provided the overwhelming number of voters votes in person. (That's slipping, and many see that as a problem.)
Preliminary results are phoned to regional election officials on election day, but the final results are the sum of hand-carried paper records. A group of people who watch the count in all polling stations could do their own sums and compare.
While one casts that paper ballot, the election officials in the polling station should ensure the secrecy of the ballot, even if the voter professes not to care. A voter cannot show his or her spouse how he or she voted. (Again that's slipping, because of the ability to take photos with any phone.)
So every country has to ask themselves, how much do they trust the programmers and administrators of their election IT infrastructure? Is the added comfort and ease of access worth a reduction of trust in the result?

"I've never seen people watch..." That maybe not but the election officials (and there are quite a lot of them, a typical office has like 6 persons for maybe 2000 voters) who typically don't all know each other before watch the whole process. It's not only distrust in IT that plays out there. It's also definitely trust in humans.

In Spain, which has a similar system, it is very unusual to have those independent controllers. But political parties do send accredited members to voting areas, and even if you think they are dishonest, as they are from competing parties, they have little incentive to collude. And on top of that, the people overseeing the voting on behalf of the government are chosen by lottery.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution, yes, people in Germany mostly trust the system enough that they do not come to watch. But having the right to watch at zero notice is an important part of having that trust.

What do you mean "a random person can stand and watch"? Does it mean I can look how people vote? I thought that it is a secret. That is why everyone goes behind a curtain.

@BЈовић You can stand in the room where the voting happens, observe that the voters id is checked and that they are handed exactly one envelope. Then they will disappear behind the curtain and mark their choice. Then you can observe that they will put exactly one envelope into the ballot box. At the end of the voting day you can observe when the ballot box is opened and observe the counting of the vote.

@BЈовић People watch the count, not the person ticking boxes. Usually the parties involved send representatives. This happens in the UK too, and probably many other countries.

"A voter cannot show his or her spouse how he or she voted." - I think that's a generalization. I am basing it on my experience as a ballot counter/supervisor in Hungary but they should be able to bring a helper in case they need so. Please note that disabilities, illnesses or illiteracy are not excluding one from being able to cast a vote. The most helpers I have seen was 4 of us (2 family members and 2 ballot counters) helping a quadriplegic citizen vote.

"I've never seen people watch" It is actually pretty common. I have been "Wahlhelfer" a few times and there are always a few interested people watching us count votes in the end. Some of them want to check on us, some are just one-time observers, because they want to know how it works or want to show their kids what happens on election day behind the scenes. And that "behind the scenes" is in no way secret. Sometimes it's "the press" to report that everything is correct (and boring).

You should probably add, that this system, as transparent and observable as it is, is still blazingly fast compared to other countries, because we simply apply enough manpower and organization to the job. Results from transparantly and openly hand-counting votes are in after about an hour after the voting stations close and the absolute secure and safe double-checked and double counted results are normally in the next morning before the papers come out. We have little need for a system that is even faster than "an hour after voting ends".

We also have enough manpower and organization to have a voting station in walking distance to most people, with the election being on a Sunday. They are staffed so that voting rarely takes more than 10 minutes. It is rare to have a queue at all. You go in, get your id checked, check a box on the paper ballot and walk out in less time than it might take to find a parking spot in other countries. The loss in transparency and trust needs to come with advantages, and I am not sure what advantages an internet-based system would have for Germany in particular.

Btw. also in Germany there are countrywide online elections, just not for something very important. I remember that I casted an online vote for the last election of the governing boards of social security institutions (Sozialwahl) with my health insurance. Online elections are done, however only for less important things.

For the sake of completeness, the early-rising random observer can also watch the check that the ballot box is empty and its being locked shortly before the voting station opens. @NoDataDumpNoContribution: my experience is that most Wahlhelfer (at least at the stations where I have served) knew each other already (e.g. from municipal parliament work). But similar to what was written about Spain, they deliberately come from different parties. And wrt manpower: any citizen can actually be asked to serve as election official, and one has to give good and valid reasons for refusing.

In France you can watch as well, and the "voting commission" (the ones that are somehow appointed to manage the vote) often beg random voters to come to do the counting (it is amazing how busy with doctor appointments, school shows etc. people are on this day :))

@cbeleites, I thought the ballot boxes are sealed before the public is let in. But an observer with a strong bladder (or a friend as relief) can watch how many envelopes went in and how many came out. The number should check out.

We have "election observers" in the UK too, and it seems we export the idea: https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/voting-and-elections/observing-elections-and-referendums https://www.wfd.org/election-observation

@o.m.: Further to this, the political party representatives who watch the count aren't necessarily worried about how many ballots come out of the box - but they can watch the counters count the votes, and while they won't know how a specific person voted, they can see how a ballot was marked. Thus also knowing how many ballots were spoiled, and how they were judged to be spoiled, or if judged for one candidate over another, for the purposes of the count.

Exactly.  Voting and counting must not only be fair and accurate, it must be seen to be fair and accurate.  And the only way of doing that is by making it possible for anyone to observe the process.  Also: obligatory xkcds.

@o.m.: the ballot box is checked to be empty and closed before the public can vote. The election process (Wahlhandlung) strictly speaking includes this and some more start-up steps (e.g. according to Bundeswahlordnung §53 https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bwo_1985/__53.html), as well as a winding-down procedure (e.g. §60 BWO), before the counting and ascertaining of votes starts. BWO §54 specifies public access to all this. From a logic pov, not allowing the public to check that the ballot box is empty at the beginning would very obviously increase the risk of election fraud, at no gain.

@cbeleites, the closing of the ballot box happens before 0800. Is there a law how much earlier it can happen? A watcher would have to guess ...

@o.m. a time limit is not needed - it is enough to require the time at which proceedings will start to be publicly announced in advance.

@BЈовић to be fair, in Spain a "random person" probably will not be allowed to stay for long in the voting area. But if you got l get your accreditation you can stand, sit at a voting station and make sure that documents match the voters list, and be involved(or at least witness) the cure counting. AFAIK, requirements for accreditation are pretty lax (being able to vote, and no criminal record that could hint at you doing anything funny).

@o.m.: I don't know about the law specifying this (but https://bundeswahlleiterin.de/service/glossar.html has a glossary which also gives legal grounds). Slightly less officially, you can publicly find information for the helpers (e.g. https://stadt.muenchen.de/infos/wahlhelferundwahlhelferinnen.html or https://www.berlin.de/wahlen/wahlen/europawahl-2024/wahlhelfende/aufgaben-wahlvorstand-zur-voe.pdf?ts=1726493982) saying when their duties start (7:00 or 7:30 is typical). My experience is that the checking and closing is about the last thing before starting the actual voting. One reason is...

... that once the ballot box is closed, you also put a sheet over the slit and the appointed "guard" of the box starts their duty (so noone can sneak in anything). And since there are more things to be done before the voting can start (hang the example voting sheet(s), check the booths, check all lists are there, organize the 2 shifts, write down things were done, ...) it's better to do the ballot box last, because the "guard" would otherwise be blocked from helping with most other tasks.

Online voting is conceptually (nearly) the same as mail-in voting. Some countries reject the latter.


Perhaps more discouraging to basic privacy is the fact that remote
voting systems (both paper and electronic) inherently allow voters
to eschew confidentiality. Because remote systems enable voters to
fill out their ballots outside a controlled environment, anyone can
watch over the voter’s shoulder while she fills out her ballot. [...]
The Estonian system
uses public key cryptography to provide a digital analog of the
“double envelope” ballots often used for absentee voting.
Voters can verify [to some degree] that their votes were correctly received using a smartphone app, but
the tallying process is only protected by procedural controls .
The voting system does not provide evidence of a correct tally, nor
does it provide evidence that the vote was correctly recorded if
the client [app] is dishonest. [...]
If voters
make their selections on their own devices, then there is an even
greater risk that these devices could be infected with malware that
records (and perhaps even alters) their selections (see, for instance,
the Estonian system [97]). [...]
Denial-of-Service (DoS) is an ever-present threat to elections
which can be mitigated but never fully eliminated. A simple service
outage can disenfranchise voters, and the threat of attack from
foreign state-level adversaries is a pressing concern. Indeed, one of
the countries that regularly uses Internet voting, Estonia, has been
subject to malicious outages. [104]

So, a somewhat more secure channel than paper mail (due to PKI etc.) if you discount the endpoint attack possibility, which for a [big] state-level actor is not negligible. So even if "large portions of the online voting system were published as open-source for the sake of transparency" that doesn't help much as long as the underlying phone OS code is whatever the average Joe spent their money on.
As for the DoS aspect, the incident cited (as [104]) was not specifically about that voting system, AFAICT but a broader attack on gov't infrastructure.
BTW, the US [army] and one US state did experiment with something not so dissimilar -- "Voatz". (It's not covered in that 2017 paper though that I got that summary table from, because it happened mostly later. Also, code transparency wasn't exactly a selling point of Voatz. But even they had done that, that phone app used like 20 libraries that one apparently could not easily audit etc.)


Russia plans to implement it nationwide by 2026, although critics argue the primary motivation is electoral fraud rather than an effort to increase voter participation.

TBH even if Russia implemented the pinnacle of research in this area like including end-to-end (vote) verification etc., it doesn't make much of a difference as long as they control who can register as a candidate.  Same thing if Iran used something like this for their elections.
Given Putin's regime track record for harassing opposition supporters, my guess is that another, if not the main reason to move to a system like this is to find out who exactly is voting for any opposition, or not at least not voting for him.
(Anyhow, from the WaPo story you linked to, the Russia system was more like Voatz, with no external auditing allowed for their server-side blockchain. Decreasing transparency was apparently a general goal as they no longer published per-precinct results either for the e-votes.)

BTW, in Estonia, it's the Russian minority there who (say they) trust I-voting less:

the best predictor of online voting was
trust in i-voting. On average, trust in i-voting in Estonia is about as high as in
Switzerland: on a scale of 0–10, over 60 percent of Estonian voters pick values
between 6 and 10. However, 17 percent of voters do not trust i-voting at all (a
value of 0), indicating a high level
of polarization. But what predicts
trust in i-voting? In the Estonian
context, we would expect ethnic
Russians, who make up about 30
percent of the population and about
20 percent of the eligible voters, to
trust i-voting less than ethnic Estonians, in part because the voting
application was at first only available in Estonian. The initial lack
of a Russian-language option gave
rise to suspicions that the Estonian
government had found another way
to disenfranchise ethnic Russians, many of whom still do not have Estonian
citizenship and resent Estonian language laws, which make Estonian the only
official language. This is precisely what we find: even controlling for higher
education and acknowledging the feasibility of verifying one’s vote, ethnic Russians are significantly less trustful of i-voting than ethnic Estonians.

Aside, Estonia at one point implemented cast-as-intended verification by allowing the user to check the vote was sent properly using a second device. (This isn't E2E-V by the way, but does at least address some endpoint concerns.) This feature is only briefly mentioned at the end of the current EE gov I-voting FAQ.
Estonia also uses a fairly centralized ID card.

Most importantly,
the government required all citizens to hold a digital ID card, which replaced
a plethora of other ID cards, from bank cards to health insurance cards, and
can be used to authenticate a person’s identity and to sign documents online.
As a result of these policies, 79 percent of Estonians are frequent users of the
internet, more than in any other East European country. In this context, i-voting seemed like a natural extension of electronic government.

In the US, many would balk at such a centralization of services, and some even at such forms of voter ID. This is cultural/political in part. E.g. the UK gov't scrapped a national ID, after an alternation in power.
One mitigating (or enabling) factor for Estonia is that they use a PR system, so a small boost on one side of the political spectrum (that i-votes give) isn't too concerning. However, in other (Eastern) European countries this isn't the case, i.e. the system is first-past-the-post or mixed (e.g. in Lithuania it's mixed, for instance). Thus in some of these other countries a small change in voting difference can result in a large[r] change in seat outcomes. So, there's more opposition to a (voting method) change that could possibly enable such an event.
E.g. Lithuania's PM emphasized in 2024 that

E-voting cannot be introduced in Lithuania until 100 percent security is guaranteed, Prime Minister Ingrida Šimonytė has said following a feasibility study.
“The main question is security, and as long as it’s impossible to answer that security question 100 percent, then I think experiments in this area would be simply dangerous for democracy,” she told reporters at the Seimas on Thursday.
“I believe this is a question for future generations, not for future governments,” Šimonytė said, adding that any e-voting system must ensure both data security and voting secrecy.
“To be honest, I’m not the best expert on IT security, but I have not seen any experts who assure me that it is possible to meet both requirements simultaneously. That is probably the main problem,” she noted.
Given that all democracies are now targeted by regimes that use information systems to wreak havoc, as well as steal or falsify data, the issue of security in the current geopolitical context is crucial, Šimonytė pointed out.

It's also mentioned in a EU round-up that

Norway meanwhile trialled internet voting in both 2011 and 2013 but decided against continuing because of public perception about the security of the vote.

Also in Finland

Internet voting was trialled in 2008.
A review in 2016-17 concluded that
the risks associated with internet
voting outweighed the limited
benefits that it brought.

And France introduced (around 2012) and maintains remote electronic voting for expats only, as an alternative to mail-in voting (which is also for expats only), but this  has been controversial enough that it's limited to some elections like legislative elections (and not presidential ones, for instance). Interestingly however, at least based on opinion poll (that I've not checked out well-conducted it was) a majority of the French reportedly want such a system, despite its issues

The experience of many French citizens [...] exposes some of the challenges
of e-voting. For instance, authorities struggle to find a balance between cybersecurity,
including voter identity, and the simplicity of the process. As explained by many French
citizens residing abroad that tried to vote online for the June 2022 election, a system error
made it impossible for them to cast their vote, which generated frustration. Once of the main
problems was that voters that had registered with a Yahoo email address never received the
username needed to sign into the voting platform.
Beyond the [2022] elections, some French citizens have persistent concerns about e-voting more
generally. It is worth noting that in a post-election poll done by the People 2022 project (led by
the ESPOL Lille), 60% of respondents were in favour of introducing e-voting in the presidential
elections, while 30.7% were against it. These results coincide almost exactly with respondents
who claim that they would use e-voting to cast their vote in a presidential election (60.4%
would, while 30.9% would not).
Even though a majority of respondents declared they are in favour of and would use e-voting,
amongst those who wouldn’t the main reason is security (60.7%), followed at a very
considerable distance by the lack of previous experience with the system (20.7%). For those
who would, the most cited reason is that it would take less time than voting in a polling station,
closely followed by their daily use of the internet (45.9%). France has tried to mitigate security
concerns by increasing transparency around the testing methods used to validate and select
e-voting systems.

One practical issue that is discussed in the sequent is that France, unlike Estonia lacks a digital ID card (and various email/SMS ad-hoc solutions being rather problematic), however they are taking steps in that (online) direction with "France Identité".
Also, an INRIA report about the software used in that election claims that

We have shown that some attacks allow the attacker to cheat, depending on the attacker model. We cannot say whether such attacks have been exploited during the 2022 election. We have shown that these attacks wouldn’t have left any detectable trace, not even under later investigation.

Alas, I know a lot less what the situation is like on other continents.

This doesn't seem to answer the question of why they don't use them, there are countries that allow for mail in voting but not online voting.

BTW, funnily enough EU-made phone spyware was used to spy on EU politicians... by the Vietnamese, who bought it legit apparently. https://youtu.be/uNXc_5W48bY?t=586

@JoeW It does not seem reasonable to assume that every country doesn't use it for the same reason.

@JackAidley This answer has been edited a lot since I left my comment and it does seem reasonable that they do share common issues such as vote security and privacy considering all the online hacks we read about on a weekly basis.

however [France] is taking steps in that (online) direction with "France Identité" very, very, very slow steps. We live in the Middle Ages in terms of digitalization in France. Just compare our digital health records, banking and administrative papers with, say, Poland -- we are simply ridiculous. But hey, we still have checks!

Curious what the source of Table 1 from top of your answer is?

@JohnPolo: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08619 First link in the sentence above it.

Their track record is not flawless. The constitution of Estonia says:

Voting is secret.

That has failed spectaculously. Here you can see the former president of Estonia (Toomas Hendrik Ilves) showing off how easy is the electronic voting while his wife is looking at his screen literally over his shoulder.

As long as we believe voting should be secret, remote voting can't be a valid voting solution.

And yet remote voting has long been used, for over a century in the US, Australia and Canada for the general public, and for about that long in many countries for military and public officials called abroad. Not having remote voting disenfranchises many sickly or disabled people. Letting everybody vote is more important than enforced secrecy, so remote voting will continue to be a valid voting solution.

I think she already knew who he was going to vote for

@AaronF It's a serious concern; your employer could demand that you vote in front of him, for who he supports. It's illegal in most places, and in most cases would blow up in the employer's face, but the more power employers have, the more likely that's a problem. E.g. Henry Ford got away with some stuff, like home inspections for, among other things, radical literature. Employers in the first world would have trouble getting away with it today, but it's still a concern.

Yeah, there have been cases of someone bringing a bus of homeless people to voting places with a promise to get paid if they vote for X. With in-person voting it is somewhat easy to notice and besides they can actually vote for whatever they want and lie about it to get money. With remote voting you only need to walk up to them with a laptop and ask to insert their ID in a card reader for a moment.

@prosfilaes Remote voting has a proven track record of fraud (e.g. that's why it was abandoned in France) and does not prevent disenfranchisement (e.g. ballot box fires). And the enforced secrecy of voting is crucial to prevent bote buying and vote coercion.

@Džuris There have been assertions of "busloads of paid voters", not cases. No evidence, and it doesn't pass the sniff test in the modern context: it's expensive, illegal, trivial to expose, hard to control, and provides minimal benefit unless scaled to a point where all the other detriments are absurdly magnified.

@JayMcEh you are right that it's trivial to expose and hard to control. As long as we do voting in the old fashioned way. That's why such cases are exposed. And I'm talking about cases not assertions, see https://eng.lsm.lv/article/politics/politics/vote-buying-scandal-gathers-pace.a102225/

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' So hundreds of ballots out of 60 million cast by remote methods. And threats at polling places have a longer history; the Republicans Ballot Security Task Force may have stolen an election.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' At the end of the day, the question is accessibility versus stopping vote coercion. Stopping people from voting unless they can get to the polling places on a certain day during a 12 hour period would have massive effects; whereas vote buying and coercion is not much of a practice in modern times. In fact, an employer would probably be more effective in changing the vote by simply scheduling a 12-hour all-hands on deck shift, than in trying to buy a vote or coerce his employees.

@Džuris, in-person voting hasn't historically been a barrier to paid voting: see, for example, New York City under William Tweed.

Busloads of paid voters? sounds kind of like musk's "lottery", but he did get caught, and depending on how the election goes may be prosecuted further.

Voting is already simple. I am not sure I-voting would make it simpler.  Walking to the voting place is not that hard. (Typically, a school. Which is within walking distance, if at all possible.)
First, everybody don't have Internet access, so other forms of voting is necessary anyway. So, not so much work saved with I-voting.
Second, how to check that there is no tampering? Anybody who can count, may check the paper ballots – and they do!
Only experts can check software. Only experts can check that that the software running on this particular machine is indeed the nice voting software that other experts verified.  Only experts can verify that nobody is meddling with the internet communications.  There are not enough experts to keep eyes on every machine, every process, every OS and every communication line.
Even experts cannot know if I broke the encryption so that I can alter the votes in realtime. (Maybe I know how to factor very large numbers effortlessly.) No encryption is proved safe – it is merely proven safe assuming the adversary uses normal supercomputers and no tricks beyond the current "state of art". But many cryptosystems have been broken in the past.
Even experts cannot know if I bribed someone to hand over all sorts of encryption keys. Changing the result is worth a lot.
The act of voting may get simpler, but the checking gets much harder with I-votes. Therefore, it doesn't get easier overall.

"Walking to the voting place is not that hard" (citation needed). That's true in some cases. In the US South, there's been accusations that voting places in Black areas have been placed in locations hard to get to. Beyond that, you have people who can't move, and people who live in the middle of nowhere, and sometimes unwillingness to spend money to provide many voting places.

"everybody don't have Internet access" As above, some people physically can't move to the polling location, so multiple options are required. And who doesn't have Internet access? In the US, many people who are homeless have cellphones, and libraries have Internet access. If necessary, voting day Internet access can be set up at libraries and schools.

"Anybody who can count, may check the paper ballots" That doesn't mean much; that means the pile of ballots you got has the same count as reported. It doesn't mean that ballots weren't added or removed.

"Even experts cannot know if I broke the encryption so that I can alter the votes in realtime. (Maybe I know how to factor very large numbers effortlessly.) No encryption is proved safe" And maybe you're the Flash or have mind-control powers. Maybe you can have an army of invisible imps to change the ballots. No encryption is proved safe, but neither is any conventional ballot system. Real attacks on real systems is a different question from hypothetical attacks.

"Walking to the voting place is not that hard" - unless you are temporarily in a foreign country - then, there is only one voting place in the country, the embassy. Best case, two or three places (if there are several embassy locations in the said country). Definitely not an option for "walking".

Expert here (in security of computer systems, and cryptography in particular, though not in using those for elections). This answer has the right message but the details wrong. As an expert, I actually cannot verify that an electronic voting system is fully reliable if the hardware manufacturer is dishonest. In practical terms, if China wants, they can decide the election. Verifying the software is very hard, but doable in principle. The cryptosystems themselves are fine, only mathematicians can understand them but I'm confident they won't be broken, only implemented incorrectly.

@virolino One of my Polish friends was able to vote in Polish elections while living in the UK by visiting a polling station in her nearest town (an ordinary town with no Polish embassy). I would say that is the best case.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' did you read the full technical paper explaining the post-2021 implementation of the Estonian system? It does not rely on hardware being reliable, unless every single verifier also has compromised hardware which is all but impossible to ensure.

In my view the biggest argument against online voting (and the same applies to some extent to voting by mail) is that there is no protection against a domineering head-of-household controlling the way that other household members vote. This is going to be particularly true where one person controls the computer used by other household members. What this means in practice, in many families, is that men get to control how women vote.

Why does it only “to some extent” to postal voting? Wouldn’t the two be fully equivalent if you’re worried about domineering husbands?

Because in many households one person controls the computer. (And it's not just husbands controlling their wives, of course: I'm also thinking of elderly grandparents living in the household.)

Regardless of the pros and cons of online voting, part of it is going to be institutional inertia. Estonia pretty much rebuilt their state bureaucracy from scratch after the fall of the Soviet Union, other countries either were on the other side of the Iron Curtain or chose to adapt their Soviet era bureaucracy rather than throw it away and start again.

Some places in the US and likely around the world have moved away from in person voting to only do vote by mail so this doesn't really make sense.

@JoeW We're talking about online voting here, postal voting is another matter.

The point is that institutional inertia isn't a good excuse when you see areas around the world changing how they vote. There are other countries that set up systems from scratch that didn't choose to go with online voting and as has been pointed out there are still security concerns with online voting.

@JoeW online voting requires a whole new array of bureaucratic infrastructure to be set up (Estonia did it among a number of eGoverment initiatives). Postal voting has been around for over a century in many places.

And that isn't the only concern with online voting, just look at the number of hacks around the world where malicious actors can control of computer systems and are able to manipulate and delete data on those systems. It doesn't matter how much bureaucracy you put in place if there are simple concerns such as the data being hacked that can't be addressed.

@JoeW As I said, there are pros and cons. But sometimes the reason something isn't readily adopted isn't because it's worse, it's because it's different. And different means change and cost.

Election data getting hacked and the results getting changed/deleted isn't exactly a "con" of online voting, rather it is destroying the entire election process.

@JoeW Well Estonia thought it was worth doing despite the issues.

But that doesn't mean other countries are willing to take those risks and have their elections destroyed by hackers.

@JoeW You don't like online voting, that's fine. But my answer isn't about whether it is good or bad. That's already been answered by others, it would be pointless for me to echo what others have already said. My answer is supposed to complement those that already exist.

I am simply stating that having the risk of the voting system getting hacked and the votes being altered/deleted changing the outcome isn't just a simple "con/downside" to online voting. It means the entire election system could be destroyed.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I will pass, I am not trying to get you to change your mind, just explain an issue with your answer and you will never convince me that the issue isn't just a con to online voting.

Because, copying somebody else's plan is boring
There are many reasons people don't just accept "well, these guys are doing something, so we should do it.  Chief among them, for me, is that, I want to make my own thing and do so for its own sake.  I think more of us feel that than don't.
Some of us are trapped in the efficiency land, where, all of our own desires must give way to being efficient for whatever governmental or corporate master we serve.  So we tend to cloud debates with whatever oppositions we can find to just copying, citing inapplicability of solution to our own needs as one of them.
However, the reality is, whatever Estonia or anyone else does is great, but we'd rather still do something ourselves.
The education and wisdom, knowledge and understanding that gain from playing with a problem ourselves is actually more useful in most cases than someone else's solution to it.

Most countries around the world use a the same or very similar voting systems which means that they do copy each other as it is.
